# Reading XML, but not exiting on an IF statement

Tags: c#

I'm reading an XML doc, and building a string with the selected data. My IF statement is exiting on the first occurrence in a while. Which shouldn't happen?

Code:`

```
            XmlReader rdr = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(responseXML.InnerXml.ToString()));
            string t = "";
            string v = "";
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                if (rdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    if (rdr.LocalName == "tKey")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(rdr.ReadInnerXml().ToString());
                        t = rdr.ReadInnerXml().ToString();
                    }
                    if (rdr.LocalName == "vKey")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(rdr.ReadInnerXml().ToString());
                        v = rdr.ReadInnerXml().ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
```

v isn't getting set, but t is always set, hence the statement exits the code. Perhaps my understanding of IF statements isn't right, if so how should I go about setting both strings? (The console write isn't reached, nor is any traps after the first IF.

Comment: I would recommend to place breakpoints on all three `if` statements and run a debugger to confirm that the `NodeType` and the `LocalName` checks match with what you expect when compare against the actual data on the XML doc.

Comment: I might be mistaken but perhaps `ReadInnerXml()` reads the entire XML causing the next call of `Read()` to return false?

Comment: Please refrain from updating the question with "Fixed" messaging.  Let the answers speak to that.

Comment: @StackUser77288 That is how it is done on SO.  It's not an attempt at a joke.

Comment: @StackUser77288 See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86278/detect-edits-to-add-solved-or-resolved-to-the-title-and-direct-the-user-to-a.  And related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question

Answer (score -2):

Apparently Console.WriteLine creates the exit. I'm a bit thrown off, but removing the console.writeline has fixed the issue here.

Comment: No.  `Console.WriteLine` only writes to the console.  You are calling `ReadInnerXml()`.  `Console.WriteLine` does not "create the exit".

Comment: ReadInnerXml() still works. Upon removing Console.writeline my problem is solved, so in this instance it seems that was causing an exit, as according to my traps the exit occurred right after that line was executed.